# How to create random name generator from input files c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have two text files, `firstnames.txt` and `lastnames.txt`. There are 20 names in each, and they are all on a new line. I need to make a random name generator in my program.

I'm not allowed to use `string[]` so I have to use `char*[]`. So far, my plan is to add all of the names into the `char*[]` array, and then make a random number between 1 and 20 and get that index to get a random name.  I'm stuck on how to get the names from the text file into a `char*[]`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int a = 0;
//Open first name file
ifstream fnameFile;
fnameFile.open("firstnames.txt");
char* fname[20];
//Put names from file into char*[] array
while (fnameFile.good()) {
    getline(fnameFile, fname[a]);
    a++;
}
```

The `getline()` doesn't work with the `char*[]` array though, so how do I get these names into the array?

Comment: [`istream::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) works with `char *`.

Comment: You have an array of char pointers. You have to allocate memory for them or you use an array of char arrays.

Comment: First question is whether there is an upper limit on the length of a name that you are willing to use. Or do you want your code to be able to read a name of any length?

Comment: can we ask why string [] is forbidden?

Comment: There is a limit, which is 15. I can't use string[] because my teacher won't let me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) only works with `std::basic_string` types, like `std::string`.

[`std::istream::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) works with `char*`. You are just not allocating any memory for the `char*` to point at.

You can use a `char[][]` instead of a `char*[]` (a `char[]` *decays* into a `char*`), eg:

```
const int max_name = ...; // some limit you decide
//Open first name file
ifstream fnameFile("firstnames.txt");
char fname[20][max_name];
//Put names from file into char[][] array
int a = 0;
while ((a < 20) && fnameFile.getline(fname[a], max_name)) {
    ++a;
}
```

If you absolutely need to use `char*[]`, then you need to allocate memory for each `char*`, eg:

```
const int max_name = ...;
//Open first name file
ifstream fnameFile("firstnames.txt");
char* fname[20];
//Put names from file into char*[] array
int a = 0;
while (a < 20) {
    fname[a] = new char[max_name];
    if (!fnameFile.getline(fname[a], max_name)) {
        delete[] fname[a];
        break;
    }
    ++a;
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
    delete[] fname[a];
}
```

Comment: Follow up question: I'm creating a random int to randomly select a name from the list. How would I access the first name in the list? When I do fname[0][0] I only get the first letter of the first name. I have a Node struct with char fname in it, so I want to assign one of the first names from a list to a Node (Node->fname = fname[?][?]). So how would I do that?

Comment: @madaniloff use `char *fname;` in the `Node` struct, then generate an index for just the 1st dimension of the `fname` array: `Node->fname = fname[index];` This will work for both array examples I showed you (`char[][]` and `char*[]`).